# How to convert dotted property names into a structured nested object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object in this form:

```
{ 
  list: '1',
  'filter.dealStatus': 'Accepted',
  'filter.type': 'longTerm' 
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert this into a structured object where the dotted properties create a nested object, something like this:

```
{ 
      list: '1',
      filter: {
                dealStatus: 'Accepted',
                type': 'longTerm'
              }
}
```

I am asking if there is a default method in js/nodejs for this.

Comment: There isn't anything built in, you would have to write your own function for this.

Comment: You want it recursive? Like: `'filter.x.y.z.status'`